# How to authenticate local Users (ASPNETUSERS)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity

I am using ASP.NET Core 6 and Azure. The scenario is that I have an IdentityProvider (`ASPNETUSERS`, `ASPNETUSERROLES`, etc.) table in an Azure SQL database.

Whenever I create a new user, the information gets saved into `ASPNERUSERS` and related tables. I want to authenticate these users while they log in, and I should generate an on-behalf flow to connect with the API along with a JWT Token.

Can anyone help me achieve this?

Comment: Use [Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#log-in)?

Comment: @Pieterjan, Yes but can we get the Token while login?

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Data/Repositories/AccountRepository.cs#L515) how you can generate a bearer token. But please only use this [for api authentication](https://medium.com/@pieterjandeclippel/asp-net-core-angular-xsrf-62c3833fd1fe) (mobile apps with secure storage), not for a SPA